# Passar dado de api volley para outra tela

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity, volley

Tenho uma aplicação que recebe dado via api usando volley

Meu codigo:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela1);

        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        datav = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textA);



        JsonArrayRequest arrayreq = new JsonArrayRequest(JsonURL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            Double ask = obj.getDouble("ask");
                            String data = obj.getString("create_date");

                            results.setText("Vale R$: " + ask);
                            datav.setText("Atualizado em: " + data);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }}},

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }
        );
```

Quero passar o valor do "ask" que é recebido para outra tela, como faço isso?

Answer (score 2):

Caso for iniciar uma nova activity você pode apenas colocar como `Extra` no `Intent`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,NovaActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("ask",ask);
 startActivity(intent);
```

e para recuperar na outra activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getIntent().getDoubleExtra("ask");
}
```

Comment: só consigo pegar o valor do "ask" quanto esta dentro do:     @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try { } nesse caso como seria?

Comment: então tu vai fazer a mesma coisa, só que dentro do onResponse.